# Empty Lines Printing After Using a GUI in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt5, pyside2

The following is something that began happening within the past three (3) months (written March 10, 2021):
Whenever I run a GUI, either using `Qt` or `tkinter` in Python, the interpreter window from which I executed the function will begin sending line feeds to the console and will not start until I `quit()` the interpreter.

### 1. Code Examples to Reproduce Problem

1a. Qt

```py
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
if QApplication.instance():
    app = QApplication.instance()
else:
    app = QApplication([])

filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
```

...*OR*...

1b. Tkinter

```py
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
```

...*OR*... any usage of `tkinter` or `Qt`, then the console in which I am working will continue to print line feeds *every 30 seconds* (I timed it).

The resultant appearance of the console is something like this:

```py
In[3]: filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()


In[4]:

prin
t("Hello wor
ld")

In[4]: print("Hello world")
Hello world
```

Due to this, I would say that perhaps, "line feed", isn't the best description, as the interpreter is not reading any `'\n'` characters

### 2. Environment Info

- I am currently running MS Windows 10 Enterprise (for work)
- Python version: 3.9.2

  - I am pretty sure it was happening at least as soon as a installed 3.9.0, but not sure
- I can reproduce this while running from a DOS command prompt (i.e. `python run_gui_test.py`) and as long as the GUI is open, it will print the line feeds
- I can reproduce this from `Anaconda` virtual environment (`conda 4.9.1` with `python 3.7.9`)
- I can reproduce this running from a normal Python interpreter
- I can reproduce this running from an iPython interpreter (7.20.0)
- Also worth mentioning, I currently [suppress the `Qt` warning related to screen ratios](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html)

  - This was happening before I suppressed the warnings and afterwards.

### 3. One Exception

It does not occur from within the `Spyder` iPython console (iPython 7.19.0, python 3.7.9)

Seeing how I do most of my debugging in an iPython console, it gets *really annoying* after a while.

Comment: What do you mean by "line feeds"? Are they just empty lines?

Comment: @musicamante - Yes. In fact, perhaps "line feed" isn't the best description, because it does not include a ``\n`` character if send a command to the interpreter.

Comment: Does the issue still happen *after* closing the dialog, but with still having the QApplication active? And if the QApplication is quit (but the interpreter is not)?

Comment: @musicamante - yes. I can ``del (app)``, ``del (QFileDialog)``, etc, but it will continue to occur until I ``quit()``